# Convergence of iterative sequence

Tags: fixed-point-theorems

I recently came across the following

> Define $f: \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ by $$f(x)=\frac{3x^2+1}{x^2+3}$$
> Let $f^{\circ 1}=f$ and let $f^{\circ n}=f^{\circ {n-1}} \circ f$ for all $n \geq 2$. Then prove that $$\lim_{n \to \infty} f^{\circ n}(1/2)=1\;\;\text{and}\;\;\lim_{n \to \infty} f^{\circ n}(2)=1$$

I thought this problem is an application of *fixed point iteration method (FPIM)*. Here, we have $1$ is the only fixed point of $f$. In order to apply FPIM , we want some $\alpha$ so that the derivative $\vert f'(x) \vert \leq \alpha<1$. But $f'(x)=\frac{16x}{(x^2+3)^2}$ and $f'$ attains $1$ at $1$. That is, $f'(1)=1$. So we cannot apply this result .What Im misunderstanding ? Any Ideas to go right track?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to show that $a_n=f(a_{n-1})$ is monotone for $a_0 \in \{ 2, 1/2\}$. Then it suffices to show that the sequence is bounded. If you have that, you may apply the montone convergence theorem. You should also look at the set of fixed-points that satisfy $x=f(x)$.

Comment: Once I proved $a_n$ is bounded, then by MCT $a_n$ converges to some $a$. Using continuity, $$a=\lim a_n=\lim f(a_{n-1})=f(\lim a_{n-1})=f(a)$$ so that $a=1$ . Right ? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, if $a_n$ is monotone. But you also need to argue that it converges to $a=1$ -- either by showing that it is the only fixed-point of the function, or by showing that it is the infimum (supremum) of $a_n$ if it is monotonically decreasing (increasing).